# Question about an upper bound

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Let each of the positive integers $a_1 ,\dots, a_n$  be less than $m$ such that the least common multiple of any two of the positive integers $a_1 ,\dots, a_n$  is greater than the integer $m$.

Then what is the best possible upper bound for $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac 1{a_j}$? (I'm only aware of the upper bound $2$ but perhaps read somewhere that $6/5$ also serve as a bound)

Comment: I made a brute force search for $m\le72$ and it seems like the best set is almost always $\{1\}$. The only exceptions I've found is $\{2,3,5\}$ for $m=5$, $\{3, 4, 5, 7, 11\}$ for $m=11$. See https://github.com/didgogns/number_theory/blob/master/211504.java for details.

Comment: How could $a_i$ be less than $m$ and the LCM be greater ?!

Comment: It's LCM. Not GCD